# Slider is not properly configured

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to modify a wordpress theme, but I have encountered a problem which I have not been able to know the reason for. According to the same documentation, it is only a matter of activating the slider option, and telling you what kind of images with references to the post and its category.

The theme using is the following

[Dazzling Theme](https://es-co.wordpress.org/themes/dazzling/)

#### User view when visit

[image]

#### Custom - Admin session

[image: image 2]

It should be noted, that I am working in local, to then export everything to my remote server, I just hope, that this is not one of the problems.

Comment: it seems your blog page is activated as default homepage. Try to change it to Home page in appearance ->settings -> set front page as Home

Comment: This path don't exist, [settings](https://imgur.com/32mu462), but if put set static page, don't show the silder